# Как сделать проверку на наличие символов из других алфавитов, кроме английского

Tags: javascript, символы

Делаю программу на node.js, нужно сделать поле ввода имени пользователя, оно может быть только на английском языке. Имена пользователей  должны состоять только из латинских букв, символов подчёркивания, тире и знака доллара. Вообщем нужно сделать условие, если есть инородные символы, то делать
`return false;`
Тоже самое со всякими французкими, русскими и т.д.

Comment: можно регулярочку написать, где то такую `/^[A-Za-z_$-]+$/` и готово.

Comment: @KoVadim можно добавить ключ `i` и не думать о регистре букв :)

Comment: можно. но я не настолько силен в js, что бы точно сказать, как там и что работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте регулярные выражения. Руководство - https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/343798/.
Код:

```js
console.log(/^[A-Za-z_\-$]$/.test('John_Smith-Williams_II')); // true
```

P.S. Не забудьте, что в имени могут быть пробелы.

Comment: Зачем одновременно `i` и буквы в обоих регистрах?

Comment: По привычке, сейчас отредактирую ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

можно регулярочку написать, где то такую /^[A-Za-z_$-]+$/ и готово.

Comment: Лучше дефис в начало.

Comment: Я не очень хорошо знаю нюансы, но, скорее всего, может быть неопределенное поведение.